# Average of Liouville function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I think that the following is an hard problem but I try to post it:

It's possible to find an explicit asymptotic form for $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n^{2}\equiv a\pmod{q}}} \chi_{\mathbb{P}}(n^{2}-b)$,

where $(a,q)=1$ and $\chi_{\mathbb{P}}(n)$ is the prime characteristic function?

I think that it is a difficult problem because if one consider only the sum $$\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ n^{2}\equiv a\pmod{q}}} 1=\sum_{\substack{n\leq x^{2} \\ n\equiv a\pmod{q}}}\sum_{d|n} \lambda(d)=\sum_{n\leq x^{2}}\sum_{d|n} \lambda(d)\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_{\chi}{\chi(a)}^{-1}\chi(n)=$$ 
$$\frac{1}{q}\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{\lambda(d)\chi(d)x}{d}+O\bigg(\frac{1}{q}\sum_{d\leq x}\lambda(d)\chi(d)\bigg)$$

and we don't have many informations on this two sums a part big-O estimates.

Comment: The case $a=q=1, b=-1$ would settle Landau's fourth problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau's_problems .  So this is out of reach unconditionally.  However using powerful conjectures such as the Bateman-Horn conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture one can predict an asymptotic.

Comment: Thank's very much professor Tao, I was trying to use it to prove the Legendre's conjecture, but maybe I let myself get carried away.